# How to pretty-print an AST using Visitor pattern?

Tags: ruby, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter, visitor-pattern

I am trying to build a simple interpreter using the Visitor pattern. I'm having a difficult time trying to understand how a task such as pretty-printing the tree can be implemented using this pattern.

The result I am trying to obtain is printing the AST with proper indentation:

```
Expr
'---Abstr
    |---Id
    '---Expr
        '---App
            '---Atom
                '---Id
```

I have defined a number of classes representing nodes in the AST:

```
class ASTNode
    attr_reader :children, :pos

    def initialize(children, pos)
         @children = children
         @pos = pos
    end

    def accept(visitor)
        visitor.visit(self)
        @children.each { |child| child.accept(visitor) } unless @children.nil?
    end
end

class ExprNode < ASTNode
    def initialize(children, pos)
         super(children, pos)
    end
end

...
```

and a base visitor class performing double dispatch:

```
class Visitor
    def visit(subject)
        method_name = "visit_#{subject.class}".intern
        send(method_name, subject)
    end
end
```

Finally, the visitor for printing the AST:

```
class PrintVisitor < Visitor
    def visit_ExprNode(subject)
    end

    def visit_AbstrNode(subject)
    end

    ...
end
```

Comment: What did you try? I don't see attempts to print to stdout, or mark nodes as visited.

Comment: I could try printing to stdout, but the visitor makes operations performed in nodes independent. Printing each node requires additional context to determine the right indentation level. I assume that the printing should be implemented in ```visit_*Node(subject)``` methods of ```PrintVisitor``` - doing the indenting there is not possible. My understanding of visitor is quite limited and I don't know whether my use of the pattern is correct or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of the visitor pattern: One version only takes care of the double dispatch and the other also takes care of iteration by automatically visiting a node's children. The latter version is less flexible because you decide what kind of traversal (pre-order or post-order) you want ahead of time instead of leaving that decision to the individual visitor. It also forces you to visit all the nodes exactly once (which you wouldn't want in many cases, such as when implementing an AST interpreter).

In your code you're actually implementing both of those versions: Your `Visitor#visit` method implements the plain visitor pattern and `ASTNode#accept` implements the one with iteration. That's a weird use of the `accept` method because usually the job of the accept method is simply to call a specific `visit` method (like `visit_whatever`) on the visitor to get the double dispatch to work. Since you've used reflection to implement the double dispatch, you don't need an `accept` method at all.

> I assume that the printing should be implemented in visit_*Node(subject) methods of PrintVisitor

That is correct.

> Printing each node requires additional context to determine the right indentation level.

Also correct. You can keep track of the indentation level by storing it in an instance variable. Then a given visitor method would print its contents with the given amount of indentation, increase the indentation level, visit its child notes, and then decrease the indentation again. Something like this:

```
def visit_SomeNode(some_node)
    puts "#{@indent * " "}---SomeNode"
    @indent += 4
    some_node.children.each {|child| visit(child)}
    @indent -= 4
end
```

You could also put `some_node.children.each {|child| visit(child)}` into its own `visit_children(node)` method and just call that for the cases where you want to perform the same action for all children (as above).

If you want to avoid that mutable state, you can also adjust your visitor class to allow passing arguments to `visit` like this:

```
class Visitor
    def visit(subject, *args)
        method_name = "visit_#{subject.class}".intern
        send(method_name, subject, *args)
    end
end
```

Then you can add a parameter for the indentation level to your methods and pass an increased indentation level to `visit` when visiting your children.

Comment: As for the first solution, how would I decrease the indentation level after visiting child nodes? I don't see how this could be done without modifying the Visitable

Comment: @JanParzydło `@indent -= 4` (assuming you did `@indent += 4` before visiting the children). That wouldn't modify the visitable (by which I assume you mean the `ASTNode`), just the visitor. I don't think I've understood your question.

Comment: Sorry, I might have not made it entirely clear. Yes, by Visitable I meant the ```ASTNode```. The problem I have is that the _traversal_ of the AST is handled in the ```ASTNode#accept``` method and it seems like I have to make a specific modification in this class in order to enable ```PrintVisitor``` to function (doesn't this go against the main idea of Visitor?). Otherwise, I don't see how indenting can be handled by the ```visit_*Node(subject)``` methods alone. Can you give an example of how you would handle maintaining the right value of ```@indent```?

Comment: @JanParzydło Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't even see the `accept` method - I just looked at your `visit` method. Let me edit my answer, but the short answer is that you can just ignore your `accept` method and only use `visit`.

Comment: Thanks for following up. So now that there is no ```accept``` method, in order to bootstrap the visitor I simply call ```PrintVisitor.visit(root)```, right? Also, could you point me to some resources where I can learn the difference between the two strategies you outlined? Examples on Wikipedia seem to implement the second version.

Comment: @JanParzydło The examples in the Wikipedia article don't seem to be consistent about which version they implement. The C# example implements the first one. The C# example should also be the most relevant to you as it actually implements an expression printer (whereas most of the others seem to be non-sense examples about car parts). As for resources, I'd say the primary source would be the gang of four design pattern book. And yes, without `accept` you'd call the visitor via `visitor.visit(node)`.